# Landau's notation for truncated taylor expansions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I cannot seem to understand the difference between $f(h)=O(h)$ and $f(h)=o(h)$. The context in which I am learning about Landau's notation is in truncated Taylor expansions. Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Intuitively, $f(h)=O(h)$ means that $f$ vanishes “as fast” as $h$, while $f(h)=o(h)$ means that it vanishes “faster” than $h$.

Comment: It's not so clear from your question what exactly your difficulties in understanding the concept are. Anyway, both are explained rather exhaustively with a buch of examples in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Big $O$: "is at most, up to constant factors" (ratio of the two is bounded). Little $o$: "is negligible in front of it" (ratio of the two goes to $0$). $o()$ implies big $O()$ (a ratio going to zero is a fortiori bounded), but the converse is not true in general. For instance, $h=O(h)$, but $h$ is *not* $o(h)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)>0$ are all defined in a punctured neighborhood of the point $\xi$ ($\xi=\infty$ allowed) one writes
$$f(x)=g(x)+o\bigl(h(x)\bigr)\qquad(x\to\xi)\tag{1}$$
iff
$$\lim_{x\to\xi}{\bigl|f(x)-g(x)\bigr|\over h(x)}=0\ .\tag{2}$$
This means that $(1)$ is a denominator free typographical picture of the precise fact $(2)$. It expresses in an intuitive way that as $x\to\xi$ the difference $\bigl|f(x)-g(x)\bigr|$ becomes ever more negligible compared with  $h(x)$'s  order of magnitude.

In general formulas of type $(1)$ are used in the following circumstances: We are studying, or try to understand, a "complicated" or "general" function $f(x)$, and compare it with a "well understood" function $g(x)$, e.g., $x\mapsto e^x$, or the first few terms of the Taylor expansion of $f$. The function $h(x)$ that appears in $(1)$ is usually a "very simple" function that describes a typical asymptotic behavior, like linear, exponential, or logarithmic.

Looking at the Taylor expansion of an $f$ which is sufficiently differentiable at the origin we then can say that for every $n\geq0$ one has
$$f(x)=j_0^nf(x)+o(|x|^n)\qquad(x\to0)\ ,$$
where $$j_0^nf(x):=\sum_{k=0}^n{f^{(k)}(0)\over k!}\>x^k$$
is the $n^{\rm th}$ Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $0$.

Similarly: If $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)>0$ are all defined near $\xi$ ($\xi=\infty$ allowed) one writes
$$f(x)=g(x)+O\bigl(h(x)\bigr)\qquad(x\to\xi)\tag{3}$$
iff there is some constant $C$ such that
$${\bigl|f(x)-g(x)\bigr|\over h(x)}\leq C\qquad(x\in\dot U)\tag{4}$$
in some punctured neighborhood $\dot U$ of $\xi$. This means that $(3)$ is a denominator free typographical picture of the precise fact $(4)$. It expresses in an intuitive way that as $x\to\xi$ the difference $\bigl|f(x)-g(x)\bigr|$ has at most the order of magnitude of  $h(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precise explanation! I know understand the reason for using Landau's notation - it was previously unclear that (1) or (3) were simply re-writes of the precise definitions (2) and (4) respectively.

Answer (score 2):

1. $f(x)=O(h(x))$ as $x\to \infty$ means that for **some** $k>0$ we have $|f(x)\leq k|h(x)|$ for all sufficiently large $x$ in the domain of $f$. For example \, $f(x)=O(1)$ as $x\to \infty$ means  $\exists k>0\;\exists r\;\forall x>r\;(|f(x)|\leq k).$ The idea is that even if $|f(x)|\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$  it does not grow faster than some fixed multiple of $|h(x)|$
2. $f(x)=o(h(x)) $ as $x\to \infty$ means that for **all** $k>0$ we have $|f(x)|\leq k|h(x)|$ for all sufficiently large $x$. For example $f(x)=o(1)$ as $x\to \infty$ iff $ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0.$ If $h(x)\ne 0$ for all sufficiently large $x$, then $f(x)=o(h(x))$as $x\to \infty$ iff $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)/h(x)=0.$ The idea is that if $|f(x)|\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$ then $|h(x)|$ goes to $\infty$ much faster, in the sense that $\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}\to 0.$
3. For real number $ A$ : $f(x)=O(h(x))$ as $x\to A$ means that for some $k>0$ and some $d>0$ we have $[x\in Dom (f)\land0<|x-A|]\implies |f(x)|\leq k|h(x)|.$ In some contexts we may allow $x=A$ in the last sentence. In some contexts we may restrict $x$ to values greater than $A.$ 
   *Examples.* $x-\sin x=O(x^3)$  and $1+\frac{1}{x}= O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ as $x\to 0.$
4. For real $A$ : $f(x)=o(h(x))$ as $x\to A$ means that for every $k>0$ there exists $d>0$ such that $[x\in Dom (f)\land 0<|x-A|<d]\implies |f(x)\leq k|h(x)|.$ As before there may be contextual restrictions on $x$.
   *Examples.* $\log |x|=o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ and $x-\sin x=o(x^2)$ as $x\to 0.$

Comment: Thank you very much! It is much clearer now. One last thing, when should I use $O(g(x))$ or $o(g(x))$ in a truncated taylor expansion?  Since $o(g(x))$ must tend to zero, for example, as x tends to 0, should it only be used when the order of the truncated taylor expansion is the same as the order of the differentiability class of function being approximated?

Comment: Yes.If the function lacks a 3rd derivative,for example, then we cannot produce a reliable finite Taylor expansion beyond terms of degree 2.  There are some very strange continuous functions..$.f$ can be continuous and nowhere differentiable, so if $G$ is the second anti-derivative of $f$ (so $G''=f$)  we cannot expand G to a Taylor series beyond degree 2 at any point with any accuracy.